# Syntax error unexpected end but its not syntax error params check in show method controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Updated with server error**

```
Started GET "/users/michael-32?tag_name=brown" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-18 15:48:27 -0400

SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end:
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:264:in `'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `block in load_file'
```

---

```
 <ul class="keywords">
      <% user.tags.each do |tag| %>
        <li><%= link_to tag.name, user_path(user.url_name, user, tag_name: tag.name) %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

The above will go through all the tags that belong to the user and pass it to the users show method in the users controller.

This is the error that I am getting from better errors

```
SyntaxError at /users/michael-32
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Something is wrong with my show method in my users controller. It isn't a syntax error.

The user model

```
has_many :user_tags, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tags, through: :user_tags
```

Here is the url_name method in the users controller

```
def url_name
  displayed_name.gsub('-', '_').gsub('.', '_')
end
```

here is the show method in the users controller.

```
def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  if params[:tag_name] 
    @pics = @user.pics.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: params[:tag_name]}).page(params[:page]).per(20)
  else
    @pics = @user.pics.page(params[:page]).per(20)
  end     
end
```

I am trying to find the pics that have the tags value. The pic model

```
has_many :tags, through: :pic_tags
has_many :pic_tags, dependent: :destroy
```

The method above worked yesterday. I am not sure what is breaking it.

Comment: The complete error as shown in the rails log would be helpful. A missing end or a missing or an extra quote anywhere else (i.e not in your show method) might also cause this. Tracking back your recent changes might help (i.e. a few Undos if you left the file open in your editor since the last time it worked)

Comment: two extra s after an end....